# Sticky Edge - getting the edge of a cell, inside a carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on an application that has a custom carousel and there is a desirable to intuitively move the inner contents of an item so its always in view until the item is truly out of scope.

^ so as the .item is moved in the left position. What techniques would you use to detect the edge to dynamically position the .unit padding-left value? So the text inside that cell is always viewable, even if the item starts to move out of position.

//Latest Fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/3124/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //console.log("ready!");

function isElementInViewport (el) {

    //special bonus for those using jQuery
    if (typeof jQuery === "function" && el instanceof jQuery) {
        el = el[0];
    }

    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();

    return (
        rect.top >= 0 &&
        rect.left >= 0 &&
        rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) && /*or $(window).height() */
        rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) /*or $(window).width() */
    );
}


  var currentPadding = 0;
  var newPadd = 0;

  function compensatePadding() {
    var itemLeft = Math.abs(parseInt($('.caroseul').offset().left));
    console.log("itemLeft", itemLeft)
    newPadd = Math.abs(itemLeft);

    $('.stick .unit').css("padding-left", newPadd + "px");
  }


  var unitWidth = $('.unit').width();
  console.log("unitWidth", unitWidth);



  function onVisibilityChange(el, callback) {
    var old_visible;
    return function() {
      var visible = isElementInViewport(el);
      if (visible != old_visible) {
        old_visible = visible;
        if (typeof callback == 'function') {
          callback();
        }
      }
    }
  }

  function checkVisible() {
    console.log("checkvisible");

    var labelGroups = $('.caroseul .item .wraps');
    var length = labelGroups.length;

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {

      var isItemLabelInView = isElementInViewport(labelGroups[i]);

      if(!isItemLabelInView){
        $(labelGroups[i]).closest(".item").addClass("stick");
      }
      else{
        $(labelGroups[i]).closest(".item").removeClass("stick");

        //reset moved items
        $('.unit').css("padding-left", 0);
      }

      console.log(" labelGroups[i]", labelGroups[i]);
      console.log("isItemLabelInView", isItemLabelInView);
    }

    compensatePadding();
  }



  $('.container').on('scroll', checkVisible);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tweaked a bit of your code - instead of checking if label is in viewport or not I have checked if label is moving out of viewport from left.

```
if ($(labelGroups[i]).offset().left < 0) {
  $(labelGroups[i]).closest(".item").addClass("stick");
} else {
  $(labelGroups[i]).closest(".item").removeClass("stick");
```

Besides this I have added a few conditions and offset values in `compensatePadding()` function.

Please refer this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bhumika107/ydt22LLf/).

Comment: that's great man -- and if it comes to the end with no room left --- you able to undock it?

Comment: @TheOldCounty I don't understand what you mean by - *you able to undock it?*

Comment: I have stuck the block at edge so that it doesn't go overlapping with other slide. Check this - https://jsfiddle.net/Bhumika107/ydt22LLf/6/

Comment: I meant - when its about to get crushed it gets released. But its ok - I think this did great

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery for this pains me a bit, as I think you'd be better off using requestAnimationFrame...but, to answer your specific question, you could use something like this (I've specifically left the two aggregate values as separate vars in order to explain the point):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function animateMe(){
    $(".item").animate({
      left: "-=5"
    }, 1000, function() {
      amountMovedLeft += 5;
      if(amountMovedLeft >= amountUntilUnitHitsLeft){
        $(".unit").animate({
          right: "+=5"
        }
      }
    });
  }

  var amountMovedLeft = 0;
  var unitWidthHalf = $('.unit').width()/2;
  var itemWidthHalf = $('.item').width()/2;
  var amountUntilUnitHitsLeft = itemWidthHalf - unitWidthHalf;
  setInterval(function(){ 
    animateMe();
  }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: I've just updated it to create a similar markup and method - bits of code that I am using in the real app. I've got some isElementvisible stuff that could be used to indicate that the element is becoming hidden - to activate the padding-left form - https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/3080/

Comment: This is something closer to what I am looking for - but its still not as stable. https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/3107/

Comment: _latest caroseul with multiple rows and different width items. https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/3124/

Comment: how can I stabilise this